# Upon restart my ubuntu commands history number changed

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

While restarting my ubuntu 16.04 OS, my terminal commands history numbers is changed, only the history numbers is changed my history is saving perfectly. History numbers always display numbers between 983 to 1984.

[image: terminal screenshot]

how ever before restart i have typed more than 2000 commands. 
E.g The last command with line number 2093 upon restart will  save with line no 1984.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Command history is not unlimited. Look for HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE in `man bash`.